# how to fast forward video in rad studio c++ code

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder, rad, c++builder-xe5

I am building a video player app for windows in Rad Studio using C++. I have implemented basic functionality i.e loading video, playing, pause, volume control now I want to implement fast playing option e.g user will click a button and video will play with double speed just like 2x in VLC player. Code is as follows how can I do this

```
  TForm2 *Form2;

__fastcall TForm2::TForm2(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner)
{
}

void __fastcall TForm2::OpenButtonClick(TObject *Sender){
  OpenDialog1->Filter = TMediaCodecManager::GetFilterString();    

  if (OpenDialog1->Execute())
  {
    PauseButton->Enabled = true;
    ClearButton->Enabled = true;
    MediaPlayer1->FileName = OpenDialog1->FileName;

    if (MediaPlayer1->Media != NULL)
    {``
      Label1->Text = IntToStr((int) MediaPlayer1->Media>VideoSize.Truncate().X) + "x" +
        IntToStr((int) MediaPlayer1->Media->VideoSize.Truncate().Y)+ "px " +
        IntToStr((__int64) MediaPlayer1->Media->Duration / MediaTimeScale) + "s";

      TrackBar1->Max = MediaPlayer1->Media->Duration;
      VolumeTrack->Value = 1 - MediaPlayer1->Media->Volume;

      MediaPlayer1->Play();
    }
  }
}

void __fastcall TForm2::PauseButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{``
  if (MediaPlayer1->State == TMediaState::Playing)
  {
    PauseButton->Text = "Play";
    MediaPlayer1->Stop();
  }
  else
  {
    PauseButton->Text = "Pause";
    MediaPlayer1->Play();
  }
}

void __fastcall TForm2::TrackBar1Change(TObject *Sender)
{
  if (TrackBar1->Tag == 0)
  {
    MediaPlayer1->CurrentTime = (__int64) TrackBar1->Value;
  }
}

void __fastcall TForm2::Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender)
{
  TrackBar1->Tag = 1;
  TrackBar1->Value = MediaPlayer1->CurrentTime;
  TrackBar1->Tag = 0;
}

void __fastcall TForm2::CheckBox1Change(TObject *Sender)
{
  MediaPlayerControl1->Visible = CheckBox1->IsChecked;
}

void __fastcall TForm2::VolumeTrackChange(TObject *Sender)
{
  MediaPlayer1->Volume = 1 - VolumeTrack->Value;
}

void __fastcall TForm2::ClearButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{
  MediaPlayer1->Clear();
  PauseButton->Enabled = false;
  ClearButton->Enabled = false;
}

void __fastcall TForm2::FastForwardClick(TObject *Sender)
{
//this is where I want to implement fast video 2x functionality
}`
```

Comment: Achieving your goal while using TMediaPlayer component for video playback is not possible. You see TMediaPlayer component is just a wrapper for default media player on specific platform. It does not allow you any more detailed control on how certain media is played. In order to do so I'm afraid you will have to consider on using different component or perhaps just use VCL inside your program. For this there are two options. One is using VLC ActiveX component (https://wiki.videolan.org/ActiveX/Delphi/) and another is using libvlc library (https://wiki.videolan.org/Using_libvlc_with_Delphi/)

Comment: is there any other option to do this with c++ builder?

Comment: C++Builder uses Delphi components, so both of those suggestions apply. Also, asking us to find or recommend components or libraries is off-topic here. Google and Bing both specialize in finding links to things.

Comment: okay now I have created VCL application form and added VLC activex plugin and it's successfull. Now when I run it a form opens up like VLC player with controls play button, volume button and max, min screen button but these button are only showing when I run the program not in design tab. I need to add code on their back end. how can i do. Thanks